# Can numpy.linalg.norm replace sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l1',) for L1-norm of matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn

I used `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` before but I wonder there are other ways by Numpy (or something else) for L1-norm of matrix? Can we use `numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord=None, axis=None, keepdims=False)`instead of `sklearn` one?

According to the [document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), linalg.norm params seem not possible for matrix nor L1

```
x : array_like Input array. If axis is None, x must be 1-D or 2-D.
ord : {non-zero int, inf, -inf, ‘fro’, ‘nuc’}, optional
```

Comment: Doesn't `ord=1` return the `L1` norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `numpy.linalg.norm` is for Matrix or vector norm.

It depends on which kind of L1 matrix norm you want. You can specify it with argument `ord`. ([Doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html))

```
numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord=None, axis=None, keepdims=False)
```

#### Matrix norms induced by vector norms, `ord=inf`

[image]

#### "Entrywise" matrix norms, `ord=0`

[image]

### Schatten norms, `ord=nuc`

[image]